# "[__NSCFDictionary isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" error without actually calling the method

Tags: iphone

I'm getting the run time error.

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b312190'
```

the only place i have called the method `isEqualToString` is in comments and the flow of control is well out of that view controller where the method call is.

i have cleaned the project many times and deleted the app from simulator.

i am new to iOS development and there seems to be to way to precisely find which line of code generates a run time error. it seems to happen within this block of code which is executed after unwinding from the viewcontroller where the call to `isEqualToString`: is in, which in anycase is in comments!

```
if ([_expenseDictionary objectForKey:@"Type"]!=[NSNull null])
{
    NSLog(@"Type: %@",[_expenseDictionary objectForKey:@"Type"]);
    _type_subTypeCellDetailTextLabel.text = [_expenseDictionary objectForKey:@"Type"];
}
```

break points reveal that the error is happening on line...

```
    _type_subTypeCellDetailTextLabel.text = [_expenseDictionary objectForKey:@"Type"];
```

i just don't understand why. please help me out.

Comment: To compare two objects, it's always advisable to use the isEqual method.

Comment: `isEqualToString` seems to be called internally by `UIKit` during `UILabel` `text` assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You have an `NSDictionary` in your `_expenseDictionary` under the key `@"Type"`, just as it reads. You have to revise those parts of code. These codes are just fine.

`isEqualToString` seems to be called internally by `UIKit` during `UILabel` `text` setting.

You may work it around by check for NSStrings before set anyway.

```
id value = [_expenseDictionary objectForKey:@"Type"];
if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{ _type_subTypeCellDetailTextLabel.text = value; }
```

Answer (score 0):

replying from another id that i managed to recover...

so now it turns out that the call to selector isEqualToString: was an implicit API call. Like I said, I was not making the call anywhere.

The problem turned out to be that instead of setting the value of the key "Type" with a string I accidentally assigned the dictionary (different from _expenseDictionary) to the key. the implicit call was 'received' by the dictionary instead of the intended string. making corrections in setting the right value (an NSString) for type "key" solved the problem.